# error in python : unexpected EOF while parsing,how to resolve this?

Tags: python, eol

I am running this code to extract to get tweets. But running this code gives me a `Syntaxerror : unexpected EOF while parsing`. I am new to python so any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

```
from TwitterSearch import *

try:
    tso = TwitterSearchOrder()
    tso.setKeywords(['xyz', 'abc'])
    tso.setLanguage('de') # we want to see German tweets only
    tso.setCount(7) # please dear Mr Twitter, only give us 7 results per page
    tso.setIncludeEntities(False) # and don't give us all those entity information


    ts = TwitterSearch(
        consumer_key = 'a',
        consumer_secret = 'b',
        access_token = 'c',
        access_token_secret = 'd'
    )

    for tweet in ts.searchTweetsIterable(tso):
        print('@%s tweeted: %s' % (tweet['user']['screen_name'], tweet['text']))
```

Comment: Does that `try:` have an accompanying `except:` or `finally:` block?  You need this if not.

Comment: RTFM on the syntax of the constructs you're using. Python is renowned for its excellent documentation.

Comment: I am not sure you want to post your Twitter tokens here.

Comment: Thanks a lot - I added an except exception and removed my Twitter tokens.

Comment: But it throws me an invalid syntax error at except exception

Answer (score 0):

You need an except block at the end of your script:

```
except Exception, e:
    print str(e)
```

I would suggest doing something aside from printing the exception and moving on, but this is the basic layout.

Comment: Thank you, I added this but it is giving me an invalid syntax error at except exception :(

Comment: If you're on python 3, the syntax has changed.